# Add elements to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array like so:

```
object = [{id: '#obj1'}, {id: '#obj2'}, {id: '#obj3'}, {id: '#obj4'}, 
          {id: '#obj5'}
                ];
```

and somewhere in my code I want to add elements to this array if a condition is true.

```
if (condition) {
    // add {id: '#obj6'}, {id: '#obj7'} to the object Array
}
```

Hope this isn't too difficult.

Thanks.

Comment: `myArray.push({id: '#obj6'}, {id: '#obj7'})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method of the Array

```
if (condition) {
    object.push({id: '#obj6'}, {id: '#obj7'});
}
```